# Powerline adapter killed my circuit

Tags: electrical

edit: apparently the powerline adapter tripped an AFCI receptacle. Resetting this solved the problem.

I plugged in a a pair of powerline networking adapters (TP-LINK TL-PA4010KIT AV500 Nano Powerline Adapter Starter Kit, up to 500Mbps). They seemed to connect no problem (the lights came on, never got a connection working...). Then I realized that the UPS powering a computer on the same outlet as one of the powerline adapters started beeping as it lost power. The powerline adapter seemed to be making a noise and was a bit warm. I immediately unplugged the adapter and then plugged the UPS into another nearby (working) outlet.

I figured this would be easy as flipping a breaking that tripped. However, surprisingly all the breakers were good. For good measure I flipped them back and forth anyways. Still no luck. I even checked the voltage across all the breakers. I've got a sub-panel and I made sure those breakers didn't trip either.

The only thing "special" about the outlet that failed is that it was added in a recent remodel (last year), the house was built in 1972. The adjacent outlet that I moved the UPS too is working perfectly and on a different circuit. The breaker box is Zinsco :( Can't really see replacing it right now so no need to tell me how terrible it is.

All in all, my master bathroom lights, the three new outlets added in the recent remodel, the master bedroom closet lights, crawlspace lights and half of the master bedroom lights aren't working. The master bath fan and outlets appear to be on a different circuit.

I replaced the outlet that the powerline adapter was plugged into and no change. Other than a Lutron Nova ELV dimmer all the other things on the circuit are simple outlets and dimmers.

I checked the power going to many of the non-functioning outlets and switches and there was no live wires in any of time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Check the GFI receptacles in every bathroom and the garage if applicable, someone may have tapped of a GFI circuit during the remodel.

Answer (score 2):

Did any of the outlets or switches on this circuit that has failed use back stab wire connections? If so try replacing all of those with new  parts and use the screw terminals on the side for the wire connections.

Have you determined yet if there are any switch / outlet / junction boxes on the failing circuit that still have power? If so those would be on the part of the circuit from the breaker box and the failure could be in that box or the next down stream box.

Did you check if any of the outlets on this circuit is a GFCI unit? If so make sure that it is not tripped and reset it.

Finally did you do any recent hanging or mounting things on walls where screws or nails may have have penetrated a wire? Think carefully as this may have caused the circuit to become broken.

Comment: It was an AFCI outlet that tripped. I finally found it in another bedroom!